# Deleted x from /etc/passwd

Tags: linux

I have deleted x from /etc/passwd, after rebooting system, I was allowed to login without password. But when I had reset the password and seen /etc/passwd, it is not showing x, instead of it it is showing MD5 hash in /etc/passwd.

Can anybody please tell me the reason why is it happening.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: For which user?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking here ?

Comment: Are you saying that your system is *not* using a shadow password file (passwords are going in `/etc/passwd`)? What OS are you using ("Linux" is not helpful - there are at least 30 "Linux" operating systems, and multiple versions of each of those - all of them with different behavior)

Comment: We're missind some detail here. Please flag to have your question reopened when you've supplied them

Answer (score 2):

A long long time ago, in our galaxy, passwords were stored in /etc/passwd file.

Then [shadow passwords](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-2.html) were introduced in order to store passwords in a separate file, /etc/shadow, only readable by root.

ps : Some people might remember when debian potatoe or woody installers would ask about enabling shadow password.

Comment: I remember a plain /etc/passwd file on SunOS4 :(

Comment: why then restoring the password his system wrote that in /etc/passwd?

Comment: according to shadow source file, "x" is used to guess if shadow passwords are used or not see defines.h:#define SHADOW_PASSWD_STRING "x" and code like is_shadow_pwd in chpasswd.caround line 498